# how to set tkiner window above task bar of windows

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, photo, taskbar

im trying to make tkinter window that shows an image
but when i opens the image in the tkinter window - part of the image is shown below the taskbar of windows,
and because of that i can`t see the bottom part of the image

im showing the photo with label (its a part of screen - sharing program, every second another image is showed on the tkinter window)

** the size of the photo is as the size of the all screen

im not sure that my code is really necessary, my question is just how to set tkinter above the taskbar of windows.. :)

```
def ShowImage():
    global root
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    try:
        label = Tkinter.Label(root)
        label.pack()
        img = None
        tkimg = [None]  # This, or something like it, is necessary because if you do not keep a reference to PhotoImage instances, they get garbage collected.

        delay = 2   # in milliseconds
        def loopCapture():
            #print "capturing"
            global im
            while im==None:
                    continue
            img = im
            tkimg[0] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
            label.config(image=tkimg[0])
            root.update_idletasks()
            root.after(delay, loopCapture)

        loopCapture()
```

Comment: im not sure that my code is really necessary, my question is just how to set tkinter above the taskbar of windows.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to read about  [toplevel](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm) in Tkinter. Add a top level from the root, and it will be on top of everything else on the screen.

Hopefully this will help you, Yahli.